# Trying to open another's application configuration file

Tags: c#, app-config, configurationmanager

I'm developing a WinForm application with C# and .NET Framework 4.7.

With this application I'm trying to load the configuration file from another application:

```
string applicationName = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1];

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(applicationName))
{
    if (!applicationName.EndsWith(".exe"))
        applicationName += ".exe";

    string exePath = 
        Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, applicationName);

    try
    {
        // Get the configuration file. The file name has
        // this format appname.exe.config.
        System.Configuration.Configuration config =
          ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
```

But `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath)` throw an exception:

```
An error occurred while loading the configuration file: The 'exePath' parameter is not valid.
Parameter name: exePath
```

The configuration file, AnotherApp.exe.config, exists in the folder `Environment.CurrentDirectory`. I have also tried changing it to `Path.Combine(@"D:\", applicationName);` and I get the same exception.

If I add the `exe.config`, instead of `.exe`, at the end of the name here, `applicationName += ".exe";`, it seems to open something: `config.FilePath` is `D:\AnotherApp.exe.config.config`. But `config` object is empty. It hasn't filled any property.

What am I doing wrong?

I have copied the code from [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openexeconfiguration?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Configuration_ConfigurationManager_OpenExeConfiguration_System_String_).

Comment: Is `Environment.CurrentDirectory` pointing to your expected correct directory ? This exception looks like it is not finding `AnotherApp.exe.config`. It is possible to read other exe.config files.

Comment: @Subbu Yes. I have updated the question because I have tried to load it from D:\ with the same problem.

Comment: Can you try with an ExeConfigurationFileMap? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before attempting to open `AnotherApp.exe.config`, `ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` checks to see whether `AnotherApp.exe` exists on disk. Here's the [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Configuration/System/Configuration/ClientConfigPaths.cs#L130):

```
// ...
else {
    applicationUri = Path.GetFullPath(exePath);
    if (!FileUtil.FileExists(applicationUri, false))
        throw ExceptionUtil.ParameterInvalid("exePath");

    applicationFilename = applicationUri;
}

// Fallback if we haven't set the app config file path yet.
if (_applicationConfigUri == null) {
    _applicationConfigUri = applicationUri + ConfigExtension;
}
```

As you can see, the `exePath` is ultimately passed into `FileUtils.FileExists`, which ends up checking whether `exePath` represents a file on disk. In your case, this is `AnotherApp.exe`, which does *not* exist. The `throw ExceptionUtil.ParameterInvalid("exePath");` statement is where your error is coming from.

Further down in the source I've included above, you can see `_applicationConfigUri` is set to `AnotherApp.exe.config` (it's an absolute path, but I've used a relative path for simplicity). When you set your `exePath` to `AnotherApp.exe.config`, the code ends up checking for the existence of `AnotherApp.exe.config` (it thinks this is the exe itself), which it finds. After this, `_applicationConfigUri` is set to `AnotherApp.exe.config.config` which does *not* exist, but the configuration system does not error out in this scenario (instead returning an empty configuration object).

It appears there may be two options for solving this:

1. Include `AnotherApp.exe` alongside `AnotherApp.exe.config`.
2. Use [`ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedexeconfiguration(v=vs.110).aspx), which allows you to provide your own `ExeConfigurationFileMap` for instructing the configuration system on how to locate the `.config` file. If you need help with this, let me know and I'll include an example of how this should work.